# Checking of users permissions

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

Started to learn creating of databases with python and MySQL.

I tried to make a simple LogIn form and I wanted to have a "User permission check". But something gone wrong.

So, for example:

I made a table with some colums. Here you can see "email_address", "password" and "access_level"

[image: columns from my DB]

I want my programm to check if user while loginning in have a permission like number "1" - he is admin and for him will appear another window than for user with a permission with number "2"

I have no problem with autorization when I just use only "e-mail" and "password".

If "access_level" from database is equal "1", should open function "logged()"
If "access_level" from database is equal "2", should open function "logged_2()"

I can't understand how to read a string from a database and store it in a variable myString. So after I could compare it with access_level "1" or "2".

Thanks in advance!

```
def check_data():
    mail_check = mail_entry.get()
    pass_check = pass_entry.get()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE email_address = %s, password = %s, access_level = %s"
    my_cursor.execute(sql, [(mail_check), (pass_check), **there is should be one more thing for access_level**])
    results = my_cursor.fetchall()
    
    if results and (**something....** == 1):
        for i in results:
            logged()
            break  
    elif results and (**something....** == 2):
        for i in results:
            logged_2()
            break  
    elif mail_check == "E-mail" or pass_check == "Password":
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Fields are not filled")
    else:
        failed()
```

Comment: You are asking two completely different questions. To compare a string with "1" you just do `myString == "1"`. Now, is your question: How to read a string from a database and store it in a variable myString? if so, please update your question.

Comment: Hello, yes, you're rigth. I need to know how to read a string from a database and store it in a variable myString. So after I could compare it with access_level "1" or "2".

Comment: Your query is lready filteing users with an specific access_level, since you are doing `SELECT * FROM employees WHERE  ... access_level = %s`. So you already know that the returned results will have the access level you are requesting. Why are you checking the acces_level then?

Comment: in consol i get these kind of information:                                                                     [1] 
['Vitaliy']
['Korolev']
['Master of production']
['email@email.com']
**[1]** - need to get this string out and use it inside my If function